# Setup Azure Network security group rules for Octopus Tentacle?

Tags: azure, firewall, octopus-deploy, network-security

I've been trying to setup my Azure Network security group to accept connections to my Octopus Tentacle, but with no success.

I know the Tentacle is properly working because I can connect using localhost, all that's left is to be externally available.

Could anyone shine a light on the necessary rules at the Network security group? Find below my own rules.

[image]

[image]

Kind regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: About your octopus tentacle, is it a listening tentacle or polling tentacle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Windows Firewall on your VM. And add an allowed access for
   "10933" TCP port. (10933 the default port between Octopus server and tentacle)
2. If your Octopus Server and tentacle are not on the same Azure
   resources and still couldn't telnet the Tentacle, You must add an "Inbound
   security rule" for the same 10933 TCP port which used by your VM's
   network security group.
   Optional:You should give a static IP and domain name to your VM on Azure. Your Network admin should configure it a IP restricted access.

For testing the connectivity. You should use "telnet client". Open cmd and write this. If there is no connection error/timeout it's working .

```
telnet yourtentaclesextrenalIPaddress 10933
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the endpoint and firewall settings on your virtual machine firewall (not the Azure you mentioned). [This is the official tutorial on how to set up the Tentacle.](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Azure+Virtual+Machines) Also take a look if your OS you want to launch Tentacle on is supported (the same link).